# Count results from textarea don't show up on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I was figuring some things out for fun. I wanted to create a page to count how many words there exist a textarea. When the user clicks on the button 'Count' it shows below how many words exist. I tried some things but I got no result on my html page.

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var counted = document.querySelector(".counted");

form.addEventListener("count", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  countWords();
}, false);

// var countWords = string => string.split(' ').length;
// countWords(textarea.value);
// document.querySelector('#counted').value = countWords(string);

// function countWords(){
//     var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
//
//     document.querySelector("#textarea").value = textarea.split(' ').length;
//     document.querySelector(".counted").innerHTML += "There are " + textarea + " words in this text.";
// }

function countWords() {;
  string = document.querySelector("#textarea").value;
  string = string.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
  string = string.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");
  string = string.replace(/\n /, "\n");
  document.querySelector("#counted").value = string.split(' ').length;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
  Count how many words<br><br>
  <button id="count" name="count">Count</button><br><br>
  <p id="counted" class="counted"></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should...

- add `onSubmit` event instead of `onCount` (which isn't valid), and
- set the `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` of an HTML element instead of `.value` if it isn't a `<input>` or `<textarea>`:

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
var counted = document.querySelector(".counted");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  countWords();
}, false);

// var countWords = string => string.split(' ').length;
// countWords(textarea.value);
// document.querySelector('#counted').value = countWords(string);

// function countWords(){
//     var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
//
//     document.querySelector("#textarea").value = textarea.split(' ').length;
//     document.querySelector(".counted").innerHTML += "There are " + textarea + " words in this text.";
// }

function countWords() {;
  string = document.querySelector("#textarea").value;
  string = string.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
  string = string.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");
  string = string.replace(/\n /, "\n");
  document.querySelector("#counted").innerText = string.split(' ').length;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
  Count how many words<br><br>
  <button id="count" name="count">Count</button><br><br>
  <p id="counted" class="counted"></p>

</form>
```

Comment: It's not returning how many words are in the textarea... always display 1

Comment: @MiguelCruz This works for me... What browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = (function () {
    var count = document.querySelector("#count");
    var counted = document.querySelector(".counted");

    form.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        countWords();
    }, false);

    function countWords() {
        var string = document.querySelector("#textarea").value;
        string = string.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
        string = string.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");
        string = string.replace(/\n /, "\n");
        console.log(string);
        document.querySelector("#counted").innerHTML = string.split(' ').length;
    }
})();
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
    Count how many words<br><br>
    <button id="count" name="count">Count</button><br><br>
    <p id="counted" class="counted"></p>
</div>
```

Use `window.onload` so that the event handler registration is done after the DOM is ready. Use `innerHTML` to update the text. You don't have to user `form` element. Use `div` for grouping.

Comment: Please explain, what was the mistake, and what did you changed.

Comment: I have added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Define button type= button.

Count

and here is the onclick function:

```
function countWords(){;
string = document.querySelector("#textarea").value;
string = string.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
string = string.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
string = string.replace(/\n /,"\n");
var count=document.querySelector("#counted").value;
count= string.split(' ').length;
alert(count);
}
```